# Why a derived class can't access a protected getter from the base class?

Tags: c#, properties, encapsulation, setter, getter

I have a class like this:

```
public class Base
{
    public Base(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PrettyName
    {
        get { return Prettify(Name); }
    }
}
```

and I derive from it:

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived(Base b) : base(b.Name) { }
}
```

The `Name` property should not be accessed; the logical name should be accessed only by `PrettyName`. So I thought I'd make the property like this:

```
    public string Name { protected get; set; }
```

But I'm getting this:

```
Cannot access protected member 'Name' via a qualifier of type 'Base'; the qualifier must be of type 'Derived' (or derived from it)
```

Why is that? The getter should be exposed to the base class and all its child classes. Am I getting something wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The getter should be exposed to the base class and all its child classes.

No, not quite. This isn't a matter of automatically implemented properties - it's a matter of what `protected` means.

Access to a protected member within a subclass has to be through an instance of that subclass (or a further subclass). You can't use `Base.Name` for an *arbitrary* `Base` in `Derived`.

From section 3.5.3 of the C# spec:

> When a `protected` instance member is accessed outside the program text of the class in which it is declared, and when a `protected internal` instance member is accessed outside the program text of the program in which it is declared, the access must take place within a class declaration that derives from the class in which it is declared. Furthermore, the access is required to take place through an instance of that derived class type or a class type constructed from it. This restriction prevents one derived class from accessing `protected` members of other derived classes, even when the members are inherited from the same base class.

A simple solution would be to overload the constructor in `Base`:

```
protected Base(Base b) : this(b.Name)
{
}
```

then in `Derived`:

```
public Derived(Base b) : base(b) { }
```

At that point, you can make the `Name` setter private, too - or better yet, make it fully read-only:

```
private readonly string name;
public string Name { get { return name; } }
```